# Handling Relational Data Input

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-relationship, user-experience

When creating an MVC application with a "Create" view for a particular entity and I want to relate it to another entity I could use a dynamic drop down menu.

However when the possible items is larger than 10 (for example) the drop down does not seem to offer the best user experience.

What is the recommended way to handle the input of a relationship between entities? A textbox that validates against the possible entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A textbox that validates against the possible entities?

That is pretty much the answer. The general idea would be to have a controller method that takes a query string and checks against the list of valid entities and returns the entities that match the query. The user can then choose from that filtered list.

You don't have to build it from scratch if you don't want to. Take a look at something like https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js. There is also [https://select2.github.io](https://select2.github.io/). However, there are probably lots of choices for that type of control.

Comment: Thank you! I like the look of select2. 
However I am not as good in JavaScript and wanted to see if there was a way of doing it in C# but as this is a client/UX issue it seems sensible to fix it in client side.

Comment: @AlexWoodward You could do something that was more server side, like a search page. It wouldn't be inline, so to speak, but it could work.